# MYSQL with count or having count issue

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL.  I have 2 tables which I'm joining.  I need to use count(a.parent_id) as countcolumn so this column will be added to the table i create with my select.  I want to know the number that each "parent_id" appears but to see all tables with the column according to the query below.  The 
problem is that it returns only 1 record and it counts all parent like there were the same..

```
select count(parent_id) as count_column
     , a.parent_id
     , b.job_id
     , a.status as parent
     , b.status as subparent
     , b.description 
from jobs a 
inner join jobs_steps b 
  on  a.id=b.job_id 
where name='XXX' 
  and a.status='FAILED' 
order by a.parent_id desc
```

If I remove the count parent id in the beginning it returns 78 records

```
select a.parent_id
     , b.job_id
     , a.status as parent
     , b.status as subparent
     , b.description 
from jobs a 
inner join jobs_steps b 
  on  a.id=b.job_id 
where name='XXX'
  and a.status='FAILED' 
order by a.parent_id desc
```

I want to have 78 records with new column written the number that each parent_id appears.

Comment: Even though mySQL doesn't require it, (due to [extended group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) clause) when using aggregate functions such as count, max, avg, min, all the columns not part of the aggregation should be included in a `group by` clause.  Otherwise the engine is free to select a single value from the unaggregated columns and return its value.  This would be fine if all the values are the SAME but if the values vary, then defining the group by would likely generate results closer to that desired.   This explains why you just get 1 record.

Comment: I would think you want to `GROUP BY  a.parent_id
     , b.job_id
     , a.status as parent
     , b.status as subparent
     , b.description` not just a.parent_ID

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group your result per parent id, you should use `GROUP BY`, but this will not return you a 78 records, since those records aren't group per parent id, this will return you a record per parent id. I hope this helps

```
select count(a.parent_id) as count_column
     , a.parent_id
     , b.job_id
     , a.status as parent
     , b.status as subparent 
     , b.description 
from jobs a 
inner join jobs_steps b 
  on  a.id=b.job_id 
where name='XXX'
  and a.status='FAILED'
group by a.parent_id 
order by a.parent_id desc
```

Comment: `Group by` must come before `order by` in SQL.

Comment: @xQbert will group concat going to work without using group by?

Comment: @Roljon the issue is getting the count of the many on the 1:M relationship and display all the many values.  Normally this would be done using a window function, however since mySQL doesn't support them.  So either a 2nd join is required to a inline view which has the counts, or the count has to be derived for each row; which to me seems slower: of course this assumes I understand the question, and I'm not sure I do yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're after the number of steps in each job (as a repeated value for each of the job details)

Normally I'd use a window function but as mySQL doesn't support them, use a query to count the number of parent_ID's for each job and then join back...

```
select C.JobSteps as count_column
     , a.parent_id
     , b.job_id
     , a.status as parent
     , b.status as subparent
     , b.description 
from jobs a 
inner join jobs_steps b 
  on  a.id=b.job_id
LEFT JOIN (Select count(parent_ID) as JobSteps, job_ID 
            from Job_Steps
            Group by Job_ID) C
 on c.Job_ID = B.Job_ID
where name='XXX' 
  and a.status='FAILED' 
order by a.parent_id desc
```

This to me seems faster than the alternative using correlated query in the select.

```
select a.parent_id
     , b.job_id
     , a.status as parent
     , b.status as subparent
     , b.description 
     , (Select count(JS.parent_ID) as JobSteps, JS.job_ID 
            from Job_Steps JS
            where a.Id = JS.Job_ID
            Group by Job_ID) C as count_column
from jobs a 
inner join jobs_steps b 
  on  a.id=b.job_id
where name='XXX' 
  and a.status='FAILED' 
order by a.parent_id desc
```